# Find the smallest missing positive int in array in js

Tags: javascript

How do I find the **smallest missing positive integer** from an array of integers in js? I didn't find an answer to my question, all I found was in other languages.

Here's an example array:

```
[-2, 6, 4, 5, 7, -1, 1, 3, 6, -2, 9, 10, 2, 2]
```

The result should be `8`.

Comment: do you have some code, you tried? why positive missing value? if so, why do you have negative values in the array?

Comment: Your title contradicts the body of the answer. Are you looking for the smallest positive missing integer or the smallest positive integer?

Comment: You should rather accept the answer by either Nina or Giovanni, based on your preference (more readable vs more compact). Both are efficient and to the point.

Answer (score 7):

You could take an object of seen values and a min variable for keeping track of the next minimum value.

```js
const
    data = [-2, 6, 4, 5, 7, -1, 1, 3, 6, -2, 9, 10, 2, 2],
    ref = {};
    
let min = 1;

for (const value of data) {
    if (value < min) continue;
    ref[value] = true;
    while (ref[min]) min++;
}

console.log(min);
```

Comment: what is wrong with this answer?

Comment: You might want to use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) instead of an object.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an array of positive integer (in this example `integers` has values from 0 to 10), then use `Math.min` on `integers` array filtered with initial array (that was filtered taking only positive numbers):

```js
let integers = Array.from(Array(11).keys());

let arr = [-2, 6, 4, 5, 7, -1, 1, 3, 6, -2, 9, 10, 2, 2];

console.log(Math.min(...integers.filter(x => x > 0 && !arr.filter(x => x > 0).includes(x))));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like below to avoid multiple loops.

Simplest solution is when numbers from 1-10, sum of all number will 55 using this formula `(n * (n + 1)) / 2;`.

the missing number will be `55-(sum of remaining numbers)`.

```js
const list = [-2, 6, 4, 5, 7, -1, 1, 3, 6, -2, 9, 10, 2, 2];
const missing = (list) => {
  let sum = 0;
  let max = 0;
  let ref = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    const ele = list[i];
    if (ele > 0 && !ref[ele]) {
      ref[ele] = true;
      max = max < ele ? ele : max;
      sum += ele;
    }
  }
  const total = (max * (max + 1)) / 2;
  return total - sum; // will work if only one missing number

  // if multiple missing numbers and find smallest one
  // let result = 0;
  // for (let i = 1; i <= total - sum; i++) {
  //   if (!ref[i]) {
  //     result = i;
  //     break;
  //   }
  // }
  // return result;
};

console.log(missing(list));
```

Answer (score 1):

I create function for finding the smallest positive.

```js
arr = [-2, 6, 4, 5, 7, -1, 1, 3, 6, -2, 9, 10, 2, 2]

function getSmallestPos(arr) {
  pi = [...new Set( 
        arr.filter(n => n > 0)
        .sort((a, b) => a - b ))
       ];

  for (i = 0; i < pi.length; i++) {
    if ( pi[i] != (i+1)) {           
      return (i+1);
     }
  }  
}

console.log(getSmallestPos(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let A= [-2, 6, 4, 5, 7, -1, 1, 3, 6, -2, 9, 10, 2, 2];

function findValue(A){
    let min = 1;
    while (A.indexOf(min) >-1){
     min++;
    }
    return min;
}

let minValue = findValue(A) 
console.log(minValue) //8
```

Answer (score -2):

Your questions title contradicts the body of your answer.

To get the smallest positive integer you might try this:

```js
const array = [-2, 6, 4, 5, 7, -1, 1, 3, 6, -2, 9, 10, 2, 2];

// filter array to get just positive values and return the minimum value
const min = Math.min(...array.filter(a => Math.sign(a) !== -1));
console.log(min);
```

---

For getting the missing value check this out:

```js
const array = [-2, 6, 4, 5, 7, -1, 1, 3, 6, -2, 9, 10, 2, 2];

const getMissingPositiveInt = (array) => {
  // filter array to get just positive values and sort from min to max (0, 1, 4, 5 ...)
  const min = array.filter(a => Math.sign(a) !== -1).sort((a,b) => a-b);
  for (let i=min[0]; i<array.length; i++) // loop from min over whole array
    if (!min.includes(i)) // if array doesnt include index ...
      return i; // ... you got your missing value and can return it
}
console.log(getMissingPositiveInt(array));
```

Comment: 1 is already exists, she needs the smallest **missing** int

Comment: Please see my edit